# finding random element from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, random

i have the array
var_dump result--

```
 array
      6 => int 7
      7 => int 8
      9 => int 10
      11 => int 12
```

I want to find out any random number from it using

```
$avil=array_rand($arr);
```

but it give me results among 6,7,9,11
But i need results from 7,8,10,12
How to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns the key for the array

So you'll get the value using `$arr[$avil]`

Answer (score 6):

Just use `$avil = $arr[array_rand($arr)];`